# How to give attribute values to each option in Yii dropDownList?

Tags: php, yii

I have a question related to Yii DropDownList. How can we give some attribute values to each option. For Example I need to build a dropdownlist looks like below.

```
<select>
    <option value="a" myAttribute="xyz">Calendar</option>
    <option value="n" myAttribute="PQR">Shopping Cart</option>
    <option value="c" myAttribute="ABC">CD</option>
    <option value="d" myAttribute="HMN">Email</option>   
</select>
```

values and myAttributes's value are coming from table. How can I implement this by altering the following?

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'media_ids',Media::getAllmedia(),array('?'=>'?')); ?>
```

in model Media I have function like this

```
public function getAllmedia() {    
        $condition = 'isActive =  "Y"';    
        $model = Media::model()->findAll(array('condition' => $condition));    
        return CHtml::listData($model, 'id', 'media_title');    
    }
```

**EDIT**: *My Requirement is to show images along with each option, for that i have to give another attribute to each option which holds the image path*

Comment: Did you see what I suggest below?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the answer in [listOption details](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listOptions-detail), and you have to implement another function like you did for options value to map each id which is the value with the image path: array(id=>array(image_path_attribute=>value), another_id=>(array(),...) for example lest assume that the function name is `listImagePath()` that return an array of options but dont forget that each value is mapped to array of attributes not just one

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'media_ids',Media::getAllmedia(),array('options'=>Media::listImagePath())); ?>
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer that N0nh4x0r ツ should accept. Maybe he doesn't understand it fully. Maybe the following approach completes your answer and improves it for better understanding:

Answer (score 3):

CHtml::dropDownList() not allow to do that..
Try creating a other function like this:

Media Class file:

```
    static function getAllmediaDDL($idSelected=null) {
                  $condition = 'isActive =  "Y"';
                  $model = Media::model()->findAll(array('condition' => $condition));

                  $combo = CHtml::tag('select', array('id' => 'mySelect'));
                  foreach ($model as $value){
                      $selected = $value->id == $idSelected? true : false;
                      $combo .= CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $value->id, 'myattribute'=>$value->url_img, 'selected'=>$selected), CHtml::encode($value->media_title), true);
                  }

                  $combo .= CHtml::tag('select');
                  return $combo;

   }
```

And in view call:

```
echo Media::getAllmediaDDL($model->id); // If you want to call in this way, you need to declare it as static function.
```

Comment: Ahh now I understand what you need... I'm sorry.
I research and answer you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but CHtml::dropDownList() can't do this.. show the alternative in my edited answer.

Comment: Oh OK feels like it will give some stuffs to my need, anyway thanks @Dabiel

Answer (score 1):

It's work:

```
<?php 
     echo $form->dropDownList($model,'media_ids',
               'data' => CHtml::listData(Media::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),
                array(
                     'options' =>  CHtml::listData(Media::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'option_array')
                     )
     ); 
?>
```

And in model:

```
    public function getOption_array() {
        return array('myAttribute' => $this->media_title);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Im sorry im still a beginner but is this what you are looking for?

in your _form:

```
  <?php echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'status',array(0=>"Inactive",1=>"Active")
    ); ?>
```

Comment: this might be old answer, but this method will fill the options in the dropdown with value and label, it is not what is being asked